# puppet master fresh installation error

Tags: puppet

puppet master was working fine in my ubuntu 12.04 server. Today I uninstalled it using the following commands and made a fresh install again. After a fresh install, puppet master failed to start.

```
sudo apt-get remove puppetmaster-common
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove puppetmaster-common
sudo apt-get purge puppetmaster-common
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove puppetmaster-common


sudo apt-get remove puppet
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove puppet
sudo apt-get purge puppet
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove puppet
```

After a fresh install, it's totally stopped working and I am getting the below errors in log

> Could not autoload puppet/type/user: Could not autoload
>   puppet/provider/user/directoryservice: cannot load such file
>
> Could not autoload puppet/provider/user/directoryservice: cannot load
>   such file -- plist
>
> Could not autoload puppet/type/user: Could not autoload
>   puppet/provider/user/directoryservice: cannot load such file
>
> Could not create resources for managing Puppet's files and directories
>   in sections [:main, :master, :ssl, :metrics]
>
> Could not prepare for execution: Could not create resources for
>   managing Puppet's files and directories in sections

Also, there is no puppet.conf file exists in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf location even after fresh install. I tried installing twice and I couldn't see this file getting generated.

Puppet version 3.8.5.

Ubuntu : 12.04 version

Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have the commands and output from the fresh install? What apt repo did you install from?

Comment: apt:   wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-precise.deb

Comment: installation was successful. but I don't have logs right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt, I figured it out finally.
I just removed the existing apt repository by manually deleting the entries in

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d**

and removed puppetlabls-pc1.list, puppet.list, puppet.save, all entries related to puppet and then invoked

**sudo apt-get update**

And installed puppet master once again without appending any additional apt repos

**sudo apt-get -y install puppetmaster**

I think I was using wrong apt source. It wasn't generating puppet.conf file at all. May be thats the reason why I was getting weired errors like that